# Is it good practice to have a model made up of other models in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, model, composition

In our shared code base, a feature branch has just gone in that contains a model that is only made up of other models. I was just wondering if this was good practice to follow? An example I could give would be that there is a `Fruit` model that contains properties such as `Name, Price, Quantity` and another `Stocks` model that contains `ItemId, Amount, Name`. The shared model is set up in the following way:

```
FruitStock
{
  Fruit Fruit {get; set;}
  Stock Stock {get; set;}
}
```

This seems wrong to me and in a situation where something is required from both models then a lookup could be done and the value assigned to a variable. If I am wrong, however, then I guess I've learned something new today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the class design guidelines, a class should have a single purpose. I'm not sure how much you simplified your request, but in this case it makes more sense to integrate **ItemId** into **Fruit**.
It all depends on the final purpose... if **Fruit** is something everybody has access to and **Stock** is limited to a certain amout of users, then this could also be a proper design.
Another approach could be to have **FruitStock** implement the interfaces **IFruit** and **IStock**